# The intersection of a Hall subgroup with a normal subgroup is a Hall subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I want to solve the following exercise from Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra text:

> Generalize the preceding exercise as follows. A subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ is called a *Hall subgroup* of $G$ if its index in $G$ is relatively prime to its order: $(|G:H|,|H|)=1$. Prove that if $H$ is a Hall subgroup of $G$ and $N \trianglelefteq G$, then $H \cap N$ is a Hall subgroup of $N$ and $HN/N$ is a Hall subgroup of $G/N$.

This is my attempt:

Since $N \trianglelefteq G$, we have that $HN \leq G$. We observe the following two lattices of subgroups of $G$ and their orders (Unfortunately I don't know how to draw these lattices here):

$\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (G) at (0,2) {$G$};
\node (PN) at (0,1) {$HN$} edge(G);
\node (P) at (-1,0) {$H$} edge(PN);
\node (N) at (1,0) {$N$} edge(PN);
\node (PcapN) at (0,-1) {$H \cap N $} edge(P) edge(N);
\node (1) at (0,-2) {$1$} edge(PcapN);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (G) at (0,2) {$|H||G:H|$};
\node (PN) at (0,1) {$|HN|$} edge(G);
\node (P) at (-1,0) {$|H|$} edge(PN);
\node (N) at (1,0) {$|N|$} edge(PN);
\node (PcapN) at (0,-1) {$|H \cap N|$} edge(P) edge(N);
\node (1) at (0,-2) {$1$} edge(PcapN);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}$

The chain $H \leq HN \leq G$ gives $|HN|=k|H|$ where $k|H| | |G:H||H|$, or $k | |G:H|$. Since $(|H|,|G:H|)=1$ we have $(k,|H|)=1$. Using the Second Isomorphism Theorem gives $|HN/N|=|H/ H \cap N|$ or 
\begin{equation}
\frac{k|H|}{|N|}=\frac{|H|}{|H \cap N|},
\end{equation}
where both sides are integer.  This equation can be solved to give $k=|N|/|H \cap N|=|N:H \cap N|$. Since $\frac{k|H|}{|N|}$ is an integer, where the numerator is a product of co-prime factors we have $|N| | k=|N:H \cap N|$ or $|N| | |H|$.

In the former we have $|N: H \cap N|/|N|=\frac{1}{|H \cap N|}$ is an integer which is only possible if $|H \cap N|=1$, which definitely means $(|H \cap N|,|N:H \cap N|)=1$.

In the latter we have 
\begin{equation}
(|N:H \cap N|,|H \cap N|) \leq (|N:H \cap N|,|N|) \leq (|N:H \cap N|,|H|)=(k,|H|)=1.
\end{equation}

In both cases $H \cap N$ is a Hall subgroup of $N$.

Next, we want to prove that $HN/N$ is a Hall subgroup of $G/N$, or $(|HN/N|,|G/N:HN/N|)=1$. Firstly since $|H \cap N| | |H|$ we have $(|H \cap N|,|G:H|)=1$.As seen through the Second Isomorphism Theorem we have

\begin{equation}
|HN/N|=\frac{|H|}{|H \cap N|}.
\end{equation}

and the index is

\begin{equation}
|G/N:HN/N|=\frac{|G| |H \cap N|}{|N| |H|}=\frac{|G:H||H \cap N|}{|N|},
\end{equation}
which is an *integer* with coprime factors in the numerator.

Let $d$ be a common divisor of $|HN/N|$ and $|G/N:HN/N|$. Observe that since $d \big| \frac{|H|}{|H \cap N|}$ we have $d||H|$.

As above we have the two options, $|N| | |N:H \cap N|$ or $|N| | |H|$. And now we also have $|N| | |G:H|$ or $|N| | |H \cap N|$.  We thus have four options:

1. $|N| \big| |N:H \cap N|$ and $|N| \big| |G:H|$. In this case we have as before $|H \cap N|=1$, so that the index is $\frac{|G:H|}{|N|}$ and the fact that $d$ divides it gives $d \big| |G:H|$, so that $d=1$.
2. $|N| \big| |N:H \cap N|$ and $|N| \big| |H \cap N|$. We again find $|H \cap N|=1$, and $d=1$.
3. $|N| \big| |H|$ and $|N| \big| |G:H|$. We have $|N|=1$ so that $|HN/N|=\frac{|H|}{|H|}=1$, which means $d=1$.
4. $|N| \big| |H|$ and $|N| \big| |H \cap N|$. The second condition gives $H=N$, so that the index is $\frac{|G:H| |N \cap N|}{|N|}=|G:H|$. Since $d$ divides the index as well as $|H|$ we have $d=1$ again.

We conclude that the only common divisor of $|HN/N|$ and $|G/N:HN/N|$ is 1, and in particular the greatest-common-divisor $(|HN/N|,|G/N:HN/N|)=1$. This establishes $HN/N$ as a Hall subgroup of $G/N$, and concludes the exercise.

Is my solution correct? If not, please help me correct it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$I guess it is correct, only, a bit lengthier than necessary.

For the first part, note that $\Size{H \cap N}$ divides $\Size{H}$, and
$$
\Size{N : H \cap N}
=
\Size{HN : H}
=
\frac{\Size{G:H}}{\Size{G :HN}}
$$
divides $\Size{G : H}$, so by hypothesis
$$
\gcd(\Size{H \cap N}, \Size{N : H \cap N}) = 1.
$$

For the second part,
$$
\Size{\frac{HN}{N}} = \Size{H : H \cap N}
$$
divides $\Size{H}$, while
$$
\Size{\frac{G}{N} :\frac{HN}{N}}  
= \frac{\Size{G:N}}{\Size{HN:N}}
= \Size{\frac{G}{HN}} = \frac{\Size{G:H}}{\Size{HN:H}}
$$
divides $\Size{G: H}$.

> I have used a few times Langrange's theorem, in the form
>   $$
> \Size{G : A} = \Size{G : B} \cdot \Size{B : A}
> $$
>   if $A \le B \le G$, and the formula
>   $$
> \Size{AB : B} = \Size{A : A \cap B},\tag{cosets}
> $$
>   if $A, B \le G$.

Comment: Where do we use that $N \trianglelefteq G$?

Comment: $\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$@Soke, when we say that $\Size{N : H \cap N}$ divides $\Size{G : H}$, because if $N$ is not normal, then $HN$ need not be a subgroup, so that $\Size{G :HN}$ need not be an integer.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti can you please explain a little more in first part. You directly wrote 'so by hypothesis'..but I really didn't get it.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$By assumption, $\Size{H} $ and $\Size{G:H} $ are coprime. Now $H \cap N$ is a subgroup of $H$, so its order divides that of $H$. And I have shown that $\Size{N : N \cap H} $ divides $\Size{G : H} $. So also $\Size{H \cap N} $ and $\Size{N : N \cap H} $ are coprime.